# How to add markers in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please help me How can I add multiple markers in this code? I searched a lot but I don't know how to add markers in this code? I am new in Google maps API. and sorry if I made any grammatical or spelling mistake in this question.

JS Code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.3833);
    $('#user_latitude').val(52.5167);
    $('#user_longitude').val(13.3833);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: mapCenter,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: true,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        minZoom: 3,
        scrollwheel: false
    };


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


}
```

Comment: Hello have a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: @HamzaBoudra Sorry code is completely different.

Comment: What is so different?  You don't have any code that attemps to add markers.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array inside your initialize function with all your marker:

```
 var locations = [
      ['Marker 1', 41.0, 12.4], 
      ['Marker 2', 47.0, 15.4],
     ...
    ];
```

First value can be the title, second the latitude and third longitude
Then you can create a loop to add markers

```
 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
```

Example:

```
function initialize() {
    var locations = [
        ['Marker 1', 41.0, 12.4],
        ['Marker 2', 47.0, 15.4],
    ];
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.3833);
    $('#user_latitude').val(52.5167);
    $('#user_longitude').val(13.3833);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: mapCenter,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: true,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        minZoom: 3,
        scrollwheel: false
    };


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

references: [Simple markers | Google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), [Adding multiple markers to Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554748/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-map)

Comment: Good answer, but maybe reference the source you got it from (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3059129/979052). And apply the code into Shah's code, rather than just pasting it.  (will remove DV when done)

Comment: which is lat and long?

Comment: can you please tell me how to add marker clusterer in the map?

Comment: You can refer to official [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering)

Comment: @Lissy Done, thank you